# How to run a windows batch script from Cygwin bash with a string parameter of the form "a=1"?

Tags: bash, batch-file, parameters, cygwin

I have the following simple Windows batch script:

```
@echo off

echo Parameter 1: "%~1"
echo Parameter 2: "%~2"
```

When I execute it from the Windows command line (cmd) I get the following desired output:

```
C:\windows-script.bat "a=1" b
Parameter 1: "a=1"
Parameter 2: "b"
```

I now would like to execute the same script from a Cygwin bash command line and get the same output. Unfortunately I was not able to achieve what I want. Here are three unsuccessful trials:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/windows-script.bat "a=1" b
Parameter 1: "a"
Parameter 2: "1"
```

```
$ /cygdrive/c/windows-script.bat 'a=1' b
Parameter 1: "a"
Parameter 2: "1"
```

```
$ /cygdrive/c/windows-script.bat '"a=1"' b
Parameter 1: "\"a"
Parameter 2: "1\"""
```

Any ideas how to execute the batch script from Cygwin bash in the desired way?

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer because I have no way of testing this, but would `"a\=1"` work? Or possibly `"a^=1"`?

Comment: @SomethingDark Unfortunately both options do not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of running it :

```
$ cmd <<< 'C:\windows-script.bat "a=1" b'
```

The syntax of `<<<` is equivalent to typing :

```
cmd
```

then typing :

```
C:\windows-script.bat "a=1" b
```

For more detail on `<<<`, see `man bash`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works well. I already tried `$ cmd /c 'C:\windows-script.bat "a=1" b'` but that does not work. Why do I need 3 times the redirection character?

Comment: And what should I do if I have to wait for the execution of the command?

Comment: Answered your first question in the post. What do you mean by your second question ?

Comment: I believe that `$ cmd <<< 'command'` will start the Windows command line interpreter, but does not wait for the finalization of the command. It immediately returns back to bash.

Comment: It does wait, you can try `cmd <<< 'ping www.google.com'`